# Laravel remove the first - in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

I'm trying to remove the first `-` in an array, but it doesn't seems to work with `array_skip()`...

So What I have:

```
@foreach (Stats::GetRoles() as $key => $role)
@if($role)
-
@endif
<font color="{{ $role->colour }}"><b>{{ implode(" - ", (array)$role->name) }}</b></font>
@endforeach
```

the output is this:
`- Administrator - Globale-Moderator - Moderator - Proef-Moderator - Ex-teamlid - VIP - Donateur - Lid`

As you can see you have the `- Administrator` but there it needs to remove the first `-` How can I do this?

Comment: Can you `print_r($role)`?

Comment: Tes, taht gives me this: http://laravel.io/bin/52Vem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$key` is a zero based index, just check that it is not the first item:

```
@foreach (Stats::GetRoles() as $key => $role)
    @if($key > 0)
    -
    @endif
    <font color="{{ $role->colour }}"><b>{{ $role->name) }}</b></font>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't think that for, the `$key` is `a zero based index` indeed. Thanks alot! I'll accept this answer as soon as I can.